# something is wrong with my code but I do not know what

Tags: python, cs50

```
month_dict = {
    "January": 1,
    "February": 2,
    "March": 3,
    "April": 4,
    "May": 5,
    "June": 6,
    "July": 7,
    "August": 8,
    "September": 9,
    "October": 10,
    "November": 11,
    "December": 12
}

while True:
    date = input("Date: ")
    try:
        if "/" in date:
            day, month, year = date.split("/")
        elif "," in date:
            month_day, year = date.split(",")
            month, day = month_day.split()
            if month in month_dict:
                month = month_dict[month]
        if 1 <= int(month) <= 12 and 1 <= int(day) <= 31:
            break
        else:
            continue
    except ValueError:
        continue
print(f"{year}-{str(month).zfill(2)}-{day.zfill(2)}")
```

the program is supposed to prompt the user for a date, anno Domini, in month-day-year order, formatted like 9/8/1636 or September 8, 1636 ,Then output that same date in YYYY-MM-DD format. If the user’s input is not a valid date in either format, prompt the user again. Assume that every month has no more than 31 days; no need to validate whether a month has 28, 29, 30, or 31 days.

the check50 keeps giving me these frowns although the code functions as expected, please can someone tell me what is the mistake I did?

```
:) outdated.py exists
:( input of 9/8/1636 outputs 1636-09-08
    expected "1636-09-08", not "1636-08-09\n"
:) input of September 8, 1636 outputs 1636-09-08
:( input of 10/9/1701 outputs 1701-10-09
    expected "1701-10-09", not "1701-09-10\n"
:) input of October 9, 1701 outputs 1701-10-09
:( input of " 9/8/1636 " outputs 1636-09-08
    expected "1636-09-08", not "1636 -08- 9\n"
:( input of 23/6/1912 results in reprompt
    expected program to reject input, but it did not
:) input of 10 December, 1815 results in reprompt
:) input of October/9/1701 results in reprompt
:) input of 1/50/2000 results in reprompt
:) input of December 80, 1980 results in reprompt
:( input of September 8 1636 results in reprompt
    expected program to reject input, but it did not
```

Comment: Why does the slash case only split, but the comma case performs other operations? Shouldn't that happen for both? Also, the outputs aren't matching because you're not using `.strip()` on the input string, leaving a trailing newline.

Comment: Just for my sanity: February 31 -2300 is a valid date right?

Comment: I want both of them to be valid something like all or none

Comment: @JustLudo  yes yes

Answer (score 0):

First off, the `\n` is a newline (enter) character.To get rid of them, use `strip()` in a variable, or `end=''` in a `print` statement.

Secondly, in the first `if` the order is incorrect. The format is month/day/year and you're assigning day to month and vice versa.

You don't consider an `elif` if there are no `/` or `,` but it's separated by spaces (in checker it's `September 8 1636`)

When checking if the month or day out of range, you're using `and` instead of `or`, meaning that it will only break the loop if both the month and day are out of range.

Try this:

```py
while True:
  date = input("Date: ").strip()
  try:
    if "/" in date:
      month, day, year = date.split("/")
    elif "," in date:
      month_day, year = date.split(",")
      month, day = month_day.split(" ")
      if month in month_dict:
        month = month_dict[month]
    elif ' ' in date:
      month, day, year = date.split(" ")
      if month in month_dict:
        month = month_dict[month]
    if 1 <= int(month) <= 12 or 1 <= int(day) <= 31:
      break
    else:
      print(f"{year}-{str(month).zfill(2)}-{day.zfill(2)}", end='')
  except ValueError:
    continue
```

Comment: @001 Fixed. My IDE didn't show any newlines so I thought it was okay.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a library that is specifically written for such cases? Try [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with two lines of code:

```
from dateparser import parse

date = parse("9/8/1636")
if date is not None:
    print(date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
else:
    print("unable to parse date")
```

Comment: OP is doing CS50 which means he's new to coding. He should do things "the hard way" at least once before resorting to third party libraries.

Comment: Interesting remark @5px. I would claim the other way around. You don't need to reinvent the wheel on a library that is proven and tested, especially not if you are a new programmer. Moreover, learning to use the tools that have been thoroughly tested and have the ability to learn from the source is imho distinctly better than coming up with some half-baked solution yourselves.